# What branch of mathematics is relevant to understanding Kami 2 puzzles?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, puzzle

I'm struggling to [find an algorithm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/51765/2680) to reliably solve [Kami 2](http://www.stateofplaygames.com/kami2/), puzzles (ideally in Python), and wonder what branch of mathematics I should even start with.

[image]

The rules are simple: Each move consists of replacing any one contiguous colored region with one of the available colors (from a palette provided). The goal is to have filled the entire image with a single such color in a given number of moves (indicated in the toolbar).

I'm guessing this is a simple matter for people who know the right field (graph theory?) but I'm not one of them!

Comment: First of all, what are the rules?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: Added.

Comment: Are two regions that touch only at a point and have the same colour considered to be continguous? (In other words, can they be filled in one step?)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: No. The fill works just like a "paint" tool. So, for example, there are 8 red regions in the puzzle above.

Comment: Here's [something about a related game](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/1wbj73/graph_theory_behind_the_video_game_kami/) (Kami 1), but I'm not sure whether the same approach applies here (I don't know that game).

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that there is any branch of mathematics that will be terribly insightful for understanding the puzzles themselves, but the language of trees/graphs is often used for describing the algorithms you're probably going to want to use.  You can create a directed graph by letting the vertices be the state of the board at any given time, with an edge from one vertex to another if there is a single move you can do that converts the board from one state to the other (it is directed because moves are not reversible).  Then you are searching for the shortest path in this graph.

Comment: @Aaron: So just a brute force tree search of every possible sequence of moves?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Yes, although there are plenty of things you can do to a "brute force" search that are more efficient that just trying everything.  Since you're only looking for the shortest path, and you only want to look down paths that are promising, you wouldn't want to do something as naive as a breadth first or depth first search.  You might want to look into variants of A* or Dijkstra's algorithms.

Comment: @Aaron: There's also a trick that always works (or at least always has, I don't know if its optimal): If there are C colors in the puzzle and M moves available, then the first M-C+1 moves must (1) "unite" one of the colors (i.e., so that the puzzle now has only a single region of that color) in such a way that (2) each subsequent move does the same (with, means that there is at least on other color at each stage with with all of its regions abutting a "united" color). I'm not sure how to express that formally or in code!

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Don't worry about expressing it formally. For code, just limit what you consider a legal move to be one which unites two regions (can only change a region to the color of a neighbor). While proving that there is an optimal solution that does this (I can generate small examples where not all optimal solutions do) would be interesting, if you are confident that it is true, just go ahead and use it.

Comment: Not directly relevant, but here's a thread about another nice phone game, [Weaver](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1201676/120540). Although it's not apparently related, I enjoy these kinds of threads, and wanted to link them :)

Comment: Also, since this doesn't look like any of the pre-built puzzles (It looks like some, but it's not any that I have -- I could have sworn it was), I recreated it. Apparently I was given the name "APleatyDeviser3" for searching in-app and here's the [link](http://share.kamipuzzle.com/0eIG/55cXLszX7C) to it, should anyone want to try suggestions in the thread on this particular puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that the *shapes* of the different coloured regions don't matter; all that matters is which ones are adjacent to which. So you can strip the problem to its essence by reducing the arrangement of regions to a labeled graph: Each vertex represents a contiguous region of a single colour, labeled by that colour. Two vertices are connected by an edge if the corresponding regions are adjacent.

[image]

A move consists of two steps:

1. Change the label of a vertex.
2. [Contract](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction) all adjacent vertices with the same label.

The goal is to reduce the graph to a single vertex.

<s>An obvious greedy strategy is to choose the vertex which has the most adjacent vertices with the same label, for example the tan region at the bottom left which has four adjacent red regions. It is an interesting question whether such a strategy is optimal, or close to optimal.</s> This strategy is not even well-defined: What do you do if there are multiple candidate vertices? For example, the second-last row has a tan vertex with four adjacent red vertices, and a red vertex with four adjacent tan vertices.

Comment: For a leaf X connected only to a non-leaf Y of a different color, first it does not make sense to color the node X with the color of Y - it is always at least as good to color Y with the color of X, so that potentially even more nodes can be merged. The problem is when you should do this step. In the graph above, you could color the bottom blue node red, and then the merged red node white. Alternatively, the red node above the blue one could be colored white first for merging the white leaf node, and then the blue node could be colored red, leading to different graphs...

Answer (score 2):

If $c$ is the number of colors on the board, this is the $c$-Free-Flood-It problem. The introduction of the paper "[Spanning trees and the complexity of flood-filling games](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.2538)" by Meeks and Scott (2013) seems to give a good survey on what is known about the problem. For example, it's known to be NP-Hard for the $n \times n$ grid with $c \geq 3$, and for trees with $c \geq 4$, and it's in P when $c=2$, and also for any $c$ for paths or cycles.

Comment: I replaced the direct PDF link with a link to the abstract. See also Clifford et al., "[The Complexity of Flood Filling Games](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.4420)" (2011), linked in an answer to the [related question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/51765/2680).